# Is it possible to develop a Web App using Symfony2 and PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I am planning to create a web app with the solution of html5 and js, and is it possible to use the PHP framework like Symfony2 combined with PhoneGap to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean to make only client application with PhoneGap and symfony then the answer is NO, because phonegap and symfony are two different technologies in many ways.

If you mean to make a client/server application the answer is OF COURSE!

You can create two subprojects:

1. the server in symfony2 (php/mysql/apache...), with restful api (xml/json/html...)
2. the client in phonegap (javascript/html5/css3) that interacting with the server performs the duties of the client